# How can I get my column to drop decimals unless it's necessary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that is currently in dollars and my prof wants us to convert it so that it's showin inn 10,000's (for example 150000 will be 15, 30000 will be 3, 15000 will be 1.5). I was able to convert it but I don't know how to get it to only show the decimal if it's necessary (like the 15000 being 1.5). Does anyone know how I can get it to show whole numbers unless it's like 1.5?

```
medianIncome1 = (housing['medianIncome'].astype(float)/10000).astype(str)
```

If I use the astype(np.int64) it shows the whole number but if I don't it puts a bunch of decimals, if i use the round() i get the 0

Comment: Are you using jupyter notebook?  What do you mean by "show"? - how are you "showing" it?

Comment: There's probably a [display option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html) for this sort of thing.  Maybe `.float_format`

Comment: I'm using VS code and running it there

Comment: See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your existing code a bit to get the desired output

```
medianIncome1 = (housing['medianIncome'].astype(float)/10000).astype(str).str.rstrip('.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is looping through the series and format them in this manner.
There may be other efficient solutions out there.

```
for i in range(len(medianIncome1)):
  if medianIncome1[i].split('.')[1] == '0':
    medianIncome1[i]=round(float(medianIncome1[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying this option will work to *show* you what you want, but the underlying data will still be floats.

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: repr(int(x)) if x/1 == x//1 else repr(x))
```